# printing crystal report to pos thermal printer on button click in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing, crystal-reports

i have done vb.net application for cafe billing , now i have completed but when i am printing crystal reports on button click its printing but the text or data is going outside of the printer paper , its not adjusting automatically ..
please help me what to do now ..?
thank you

```
  Dim report As New bill
  report.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0)
```

this above is my code to print on default printer but its printing data outside the pages its not auto adjusting

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are talking about adjusting the text with the width of the thermal paper. If so, you can set the width of the paper in the Crystal report. To do so, right click on the crystal report, select Design->Page Setup and now you will be seeing Page Setup dialog box. Under Printer options group, Uncheck "No Printer" check box and select your thermal printer in the next drop down box. if you are not seeing your thermal printer there then you haven't setup your printer properly. Under Page Options, select "Roll paper 80 * 297 mm" or something else which suites your requirement. Keep the Orientation as portrait. Click OK to close the dialog. Now you should be able to see the Crystal report automatically changed the width in design time itself to suit your thermal printer.

Comment: what about paper variable height? Will crystal take the height automatically and cut the page?